# Singularities in Bianchi models in general relativity ( physical science)

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, string-theory, cosmology

what are the conditions to check point  type singularity in a bianchi type model ?
bianchi type model are of Type I,II,III,IX,IV or u can say we use different Bianchi type models  having some specific metric or line element as i know .

Comment: could you change the title so some of the specific content of the question is in it, please?

Comment: i added as u suggest i have read some papers through internet and want to know how to check that term.